# Theory on a topic: Is it "(noun) + theory" or "(adj.) + theory"?

Tags: word-choice

In academic writings, when mentioning about a theory on some topic, which is better, "(the noun word of the topic) + theory", or "(the adjective word of the topic) + theory"?

For example, topology theory v.s. topological theory, category theory v.s. categorical theory, mechanics theory v.s. mechanical theory?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/why-is-it-geometric-but-theoretical

Comment: In a phrase like "number theory", I'm not so sure it's right to call _number_ a noun. In that context, the word is a qualifier, and qualifiers can be words that are nouns, adjectives, or either a noun or an adjective, depending on the context.

Comment: I am.  Nouns commonly function in attributive position and *number* doesn't have any traits that would distinguish it as an adjective.  Might as well call it a noun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the specific theory. Judging from an unscientific sample, within mathematics, (noun) + theory is more common.

In math, we have *category theory*, *number theory*, *representation theory*, *group theory*, and *graph theory*, which are all nouns, but we also have *combinatorial theory* and *spectral theory*, which are both adjectives. Mathematicians would never say *representational theory* or *spectrum theory*, even though they use the words *representational* and *spectrum* when talking about subjects within these theories.

Even outside of science, we see both (adjective) + theory and (noun) + theory; for example, *literary theory* and *music theory*.

For some of these, there's a reason to use the noun or adjective; for example, there's no good adjective for *group*. But for most of these, the decision seems fairly arbitrary.

Comment: Adjective theory is more common - at least according to ngrams: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_NOUN_+theory%2C+_ADJ_+theory&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C_NOUN_%20theory%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_ADJ_%20theory%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Matt: that's an interesting theory, but I'd like more evidence that you aren't seeing a lot of hits for *ADJ theory* which aren't actually the name of a theory.

Comment: Thanks! Which one is correct,  topology theory or topological theory? Topological vector space theory, or topological vector spaces?

Comment: If you're talking about the field of mathematics, I'd just say *topology*. It doesn't need a *theory* after it, like *chemistry*.

Comment: So is it fine to say I have studied measure theory, topology, topological vector spaces, and category theory? What would you suggest instead?

Comment: I think *"measure theory, topology, topological vector spaces, and category theory"* is fine.